# Synchronous changes to webpages useing javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is most likely a very simple question but i am new to server-client programming i am used to only a client. I want an action that is taken on one person's browser to effect the state of the screen to all people that are looking at it.

I doubt it is that hard but i have no idea. And after some googling i can't find anything.

Comment: **And after some googling i can't find anything.**. Yes, sure.

Comment: PubSub or similar. But yes, it is hard, if you never did it before.

Comment: "I want an action that is taken on one person's browser to effect the state of the screen to all people that are looking at it." Won't this be a perfect job for Node.js ? ?

Comment: @Marcin well i assumed it was there but my google searches didn't come up with anything. When you have no idea what something is called not even google can help you.

smerny, thriqon Thanks i'll look those up

Comment: Check web sockets, node.js, ajax, things like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), which allow you to open up a constant connection between the client and the server.

Basically you will need the "host" to send its screen data to the server via websocket (or possibly AJAX), which can then transfer the data to the "viewers" (which is where the websockets will be superior to AJAX).